# How to customize language in azure adb2c

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using azure adb2c to customize the language and following below tutorial to customize the language to Spanish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization

So first i have downloaded the existing Spanish version and found existing spanish content in json file. for example.

```
{
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "local_intro_username",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Iniciar sesión con su nombre de usuario"
    },
```

i want to change the test of highlighted string "Mantener la sesión iniciada"
to "Test" but the corresponding string id i am not getting in json file. then how i can change the text.[here is attached image, and i want to change the highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IV0G.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below JSON element to override KMSI (Keep Me Signed In) in SUSI policy.

```
 {
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "remember_me",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Your Own String"
}
```

But Currently, There is an **issue** in Basic Policies and because of that, it is not allowing you to override.

**Alternate Approach:**
You can use custom policies/ Javascript to get this work

Javascript:

1. Enable JS in basic policies
2. Update your custom URI for Unified Sign in or Signup page
3. Put below script in your custom HTML page (include JQuery URL in your HTML page)

Script:

```
$('label[for=rememberMe]').text("My Custom Text");
```

Click [here](https://cpimtestrk.b2clogin.com/cpimtestrk.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SUSIV2CustomJS&client_id=c220d7e1-9991-4e27-8abb-0cf0a15c004d&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login) to test

Custom Policies (Pretty Stright no need of Javascript)

1. Update custom policies to use the new page contract (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-contract)
2. Enable Language Customization in custom policies and put below line to reflect changes

```html
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="remember_me">My Custom Text</LocalizedString>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can review the next,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids

OR

using Jquery (Azure AD B2C uses a specific version of jQuery. Don’t include another version of jQuery. Using more than one version on the same page causes issues.)

you can also enable javascript (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) and then use

```
$("label[for='signInName']").text("Correo Electrónico");
```